# SEO, same page but with URL rewrite

Tags: php, html, seo

if I had one PHP page, and based on the `id` passed to it the content it loads would be different, and then I rewrite the URL.

How will this affect the SEO? I understand that it would be better to have each page as a separate page, but the data for that page is added to the DB and the page loads it dynamically.

Each `.php?id=..` will have its own page rewrite and be lined on the page.

Answer (score 0):

Get a better rewriting scheme. Have a table mapping human readable names to ids:

```
--------------------------
|  id     |  name        |
|---------|--------------|
|  1      | main_page    |
|  2      | comment_page |
          ...
```

Then have a rewrite rule the rewrites `http://www.yoursite.com/${NAME}` into `http://www.yoursite.com/pagething.php?name=${NAME}`. Then do a lookup to get the `id` from the `name`, and display the page as usual.